# Keras, anaconda envs, and various Backends

Tags: keras, anaconda

I installed and configured theano, tensorflow, and cntk into diverse anaconda environments. I have installed keras in each environment as well.

Now, I'd like to use keras with those various backends in each one of these envs. Without having to edit the main (global) keras.json each time in my home dir.

Is it possible? Thanks.

Important note: my question holds for both windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible but it's not builtin. You have to write a function for that:

```
from keras import backend as K
import os
from importlib import reload

def set_keras_backend(backend):

    if K.backend() != backend:
        os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = backend
        reload(K)
        assert K.backend() == backend

set_keras_backend("theano")
```

Comment: Useful aswer, upvoted. Let's see if someone else suggest other solutions, too.